# Firebase get last child producing null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase and I would like to get the last key (message). However with my code it is just producing NPE.  The structure of the fb database can be seen here:

[image: Structure of DB]

```
Query lastQuery = rootRef.child("Chatmessages").child(last).child(userid).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString(); // Error on this line
        // viewHolder.setUserStatus(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returns an array and not a single object, so you should loop over the `dataSnapShot` to get the only object it has: the last chat...

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String message = child.child("message").getValue().toString();
        // viewHolder.setUserStatus(message);
    }
}
```